# Если перейти из "без принятого ответа" в "все вопросы", то в фильтр добавляются все метки, на которые подписан

Tags: дефект, метки, вопросы

1. Перейти в ["без принятого ответа"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered).
2. Потом нажать на "все вопросы".
3. В фильтр подставятся все метки, на которые я подписан.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще, ссылка должна вести на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: Не воспроизводится

Comment: А у меня воспроизводится

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что переходя по ссылке из п.1 учитывается предыстория, то есть на какой вкладке вы были ранее на этой странице. И если это была вкладка «с отслеживаемыми метками» (это видно перед нажатием ссылки «без принятого ответа»), то в итоге получится описанное поведение. Если это были другие вкладки, такого не наблюдается. Имхо, так задумано.

Comment: Ага, так получилось воспроизвести, получается проблемы нет

Comment: Тогда почему у нас по дефолту вопросы по моим меткам, а на en SO нет?

Comment: Все равно это баг, потому что вкладка "с отслеживаемыми метками" объединяет их через ИЛИ, а в фильтр подставляется И.